# Get my posts on facebook manage page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need get ME posts in one of my manage pages, with the new version of facebook sdk.

**Example**:

I'm manage on Page A, and add a post in my name Adexe Rivera, and in this page there are a lot of posts. So I want to filter only posts by Adexe Rivera.

I know for get posts on pages it's necesary /page/feed, but I need add the filter from user.

I tried with Graph Api Explorer, with this FQL:

```
SELECT source_id, actor_id, post_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = "PAGE_ID" AND actor_id = "MY_ID"
```

and get the information that I'm searching.

But I know that since v2.0 FQL not works for sdk, so that I need it's make the same like FQL works in this version of graph

I already tried what [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed/) said, but not get my posts.

```
A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Filtering is not possible, you can only use the existing endpoints and filter on your own after getting the entries. There are several different endpoints, make sure you are using the correct one. They are all documented very well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed

Also, an App Access Token should be enough to get access to the endpoints if it´s a public post on a non-restricted Page:

> An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.

If you don´t know about Access Tokens, read those articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Hi Luschn, and thanks for your answer, of course that I read access tokens, but the case that I search it doesn't work, and it is a pity that what worked before, I mean the FQL, they have been removed and they have not adequately replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it is not possible to use FQL giving me the expected result, so getting the "from" field in the **/PAGEID/feed** endpoint, and filtering the results, I get what I wanted.

Thanks for your answers and for their penalties, I have spent several days trying to maximize the performance of the SDK facebook.

Cheers